# Problem with adding folder to the side bar

Tags: directory

I'm trying to drag and drop a folder to the sidebar so that I can access it quicker instead of going into several directories until I find my folder. But so far I couldn't do it! Is there a solution to put folders to the sidebar for quicker access?
I have Ubuntu 20.

Comment: When you say 20... is it `20.04` or `20.10`?

Comment: @ThunderBird it's 20.04

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to be specific.

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly supported in Ubuntu desktop based on Gnome Shell. The dock hosts applications, not files.

To quickly access folders, you can use bookmark folders. You also could create a folder and populate it with symlinks to folders for quick access.

What you can do, though, is [create a `.desktop` launcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/64237/558158) for the folder in your `.local/share/applications` folder. Supply `nautilus <folderpath>`, or even better `xdg-open <folderpath>` on the `Exec=` line. Such launcher will appear in the Application overview, from where you could pin it as a favorite on the dock. By default, there is no way to create a `.desktop` file through the GUI, but you still could install `menulibre` or `alacarte` to do this.

Comment: Couldn't you do this with the Menu Editor? I'm not sure because I haven't tried such a thing. `sudo apt install menulibre`

Comment: @Alejandro probably yes, but I am not familiar with the tool. Anyhow, I added this and alacarte to the answer. Alacarte is also mentioned in the link I provided.

Comment: @vanadium thanks for your answer but I'm not sure if this answers my question. Even the starred files just works for starred files not folders! I am not sure how can I star a folder!

Comment: @alejandro I checked the menulibre! it's for changing menu for libre office not the quick access for folders!

Comment: There is more in my answer than the starred folders. Anyway, I removed that aspect - I disable tracker so I can and do not use that feature. Did not know you cannot star folders. I am just telling you in my answer how the status is. By default, it is not supported in the GUI but still you can do in other ways. Sorry that this disappoints you, but that is how it is, unless someone comes around with something I did not know about. With menulibre, you can add any command you want. I think you need to carefully reread the answer before jumping to conclusions.